# Guidance needs to setup datalake

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, azure-data-lake, data-lake

I need some guidance in setting up datalake:

1. We are pulling data from source (rest api) which returns JSON file. Sample structure given below.

```
{
    "version": "3.0",
    "name": "application_name",
    ...
    "request":
    {
        "startdate": "" ,
        "enddate": "",
        "records": 1000
        ...
    }
    "ranking":
    {
        "90":
        {
            "name": "somename",
            "class": "someclass"
            ..
        },
        "98":
        {
            "name": "somename",
            "class": "someclass"
            ..
        }
        "86":
        {
            "name": "somename",
            "class": "someclass"
            ..
        }   
    }
}
```

2. We are planning to store this information in datalake and hence I had following questions:

   > A. We are planning to dump data under directory [YEAR] - [MONTH] - [FILE_.json]. What is the advantage in splitting the directory by [Year] and [Month] in comparion to storing [FILE_.json] in root directory?

   > B. If we are extracting data multiple times (say every hour), then shall I overwrite [FILE_.json] or appending the file is better?

   > C. Is it advisable to store data as it is from source or better to store required data. In this case data under "ranking" attribute.

   > D. Consider I notice that data for last 10 days hasn't been extracted. In this situation, if I extract data for last 10 days, it will store all the data in a single file [FILE_.json]. Is it good way of storing data? For getting data from source, I have to pass startdata and enddate. It would be easier to get all 10 days data in a single call rather than making 10 different calls.

   > E. Is it advisable to add additional attributes to JSON file like following:
   > - ingestdt
   > - tags??

   > F. In future, if we are extracting data from another source, should I combine data and dump it in single json or should I have different JSON file. JSON structure between different sources will be different? Which method would be easier for downstream consumption?

I will be grateful if someone can please guide us in right direction. Any inputs will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below are the answers to all your questions.

**A.** Advantage of splitting or filtering the data on [YEAR] and [MONTH] will help you to manage it. You will be able to identify the data based on per month, date, hours for future reference. If you have loaded all the data in a single file, it will be difficult to process further. Therefore, sorting the data is the recommended approach in any given case.

**B.** Overwriting the file or appending it totally depends on your use case. If your application may need previous data in future, it is better to append. Or, if the previous data is useless and won't be required in future, then simply overwrite it and save your storage memory.

**C.** It is always advisable to store only required data. Storing unrequired data will use unnecessary storage. Clean your data using Azure Data Factory data flow and store the output in data lake.

**D.** Technically you should manage the same hierarchy as mentioned in **answer A** to manage data properly. Split your data per day basis for easy processing.

**E.** This is not mandatory but you can if want to. As you are already splitting it on per day basis, no extra tags required.

**F.** When extracting data from different source, always keep it in separate JSON file so that it would be easy to identify and there will be no confusion. Create a separate folder structure and store data there.

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT, Thank you for your inputs. It helps. I had follow-on questions please:

Comment: Please update your question with follow-up questions.

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT, sorry, somehow my questions was missing. Here it is: "This is regarding point D. Consider I am storing my data as follows:

<ingest_dt>.json -> this is generated for each day.

Now if I have to extract last 10 days data (because it was missed), then should I create 10 files with <respective date>_dt.json for each day or I should load all the 10 days data in <current ingest_dt>.json? If I load it in <respective date>_dt.json then I am not sure how downstream processors will know, there are 10 new files (but with older dates) which needs to be processed." Many thanks.

Comment: As per my understanding, you should create 10 separate files for each day in case you missed for those days. This is because you are already managing same hierarchy in your structure and by following this it would be easy to differentiate each day data in future if required. If you are saving all the 10 days data in single file, it would be difficult to analyze. This is my advice, rest depends on your use case. If this data won't be required for any further process, you can save it in single file.

Comment: Hello @UtkarshPal-MT. I agree that it is better to save data in 10 different files. For ex, if I missed data for 1st Feb to 10-Feb, then it would be:

file_010222.json
file_020222.json..

In this case, how downstream application will know, these are 10 new files which needs to be processed. Initially I thought to store the files as follows:

file_<ingestdt>.json

In this way, downstream application will look for file_<currentdate> which will match to ingestdt and all the data will be processed. But if I separate the files, then what will be the logic for downstream processing?

Comment: One logic is this: after processing the file, move it to another location. Just keep the new files in your main folder.

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT, Thank you again for guiding me.

Comment: Please accept this solution as an answer (click on the check mark on left side of answer) if it helped you to clear your doubts. This will help other community members also. Thank you!